# On counting number of vertices that have common neighbor

Tags: algorithms

Suppose given a graph $G(V,E)$ that we want to count the number of pair of vertices that have common neighbor.

I think for any pair in $\binom{|V|}{2}$ we must check its neighbor  that is common or not. So the running time is $O(V^3)$ in complete graphs.

My question is, are there simpler algorithm that run in $o(|V|^3)$?

Comment: Is it required that such a pair will also have an edge between the two vertices?

Comment: What I meant is the following: Assume $v,u$ are the pair and $w$ is their common neighbor. Do we require that $(v,u)$ is an edge, or do we allow $v,u$ to be a "valid" pair even without having this edge?

Comment: How is the graph represented? Do you want a theoretical solution, or do you also want to do this quickly in practice?

Comment: This can be done in O(n^2) time if we allow O(n^2) memory, as we can iterate over all vertices followed by each pair of their neighbors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a faster algorithm by using matrix multiplication. Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of $G$, and compute $B=A^2$. Since $b_{ik} = \sum_{j=1}^{|V|} a_{ij}a_{jk}$, the entry $b_{ik}$ is equal to the number of vertices that are adjacent to both $v_i$ and $v_k$. So, the total number of pairs that have a common neighbour is the number of non-zero entries in $B$.

Matrix multiplication can be done in $O(|V|^\omega)$, and counting the entries of $B$ in $O(|V|^2)$, so this algorithm runs in time $O(|V|^\omega)$. ($\omega$ is the smallest number s.t. any two $n\times n$ matrices can be computed in $O(n^\omega)$ time) Since $\omega <3$, this algorithm runs in $o(|V|^3)$. How simple the algorithm will be depends on what algorithm you choose to do matrix multiplication.